# How can I add a waveform to quartus?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm about to create a new wave from file in a VHDL project in Quartus, but I've failed to find waveform type in verification part of the place.

Where we add a new file to a project, what can I do?

I'm using the web edition of Quartus.

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about Quartus 2 vector waveform, this tool is no longer supported since v.10.